# Appending a char to a char* in C?

Tags: c, string, char, append

I'm trying to make a quick function that gets a word/argument in a string by its number:

```
char* arg(char* S, int Num) {
    char* Return = "";
    int Spaces = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i<strlen(S); i++) {
        if (S[i] == ' ') {
            Spaces++;
        }
        else if (Spaces == Num) {
            //Want to append S[i] to Return here.
        }
        else if (Spaces > Num) {
            return Return;
        }
    }
    printf("%s-\n", Return);
    return Return;
}
```

I can't find a way to put the characters into `Return`. I have found lots of posts that suggest `strcat()` or tricks with pointers, but every one segfaults. I've also seen people saying that `malloc()` should be used, but I'm not sure of how I'd used it in a loop like this.

Comment: `Return` is a temporary. It will be gone when it goes out of scope (e.g.: when returning), unless you `malloc` it first.

Comment: @0xC0000022L But this question is tagged `C`, not `C++`.

Comment: +1 because I believe this is a good c learning example

Answer (score 2):

I will not claim to understand what it is that you're trying to do, but your code has two problems:

- You're assigning a read-only string to `Return`; that string will be in your
  binary's data section, which is read-only, and if you try to modify it you will get a segfault.
- Your for loop is O(n^2), because `strlen()` is O(n)

There are several different ways of solving the "how to return a string" problem. You can, for example:

- Use `malloc()` / `calloc()` to allocate a new string, as has been suggested
- Use `asprintf()`, which is similar but gives you formatting if you need
- Pass an output string (and its maximum size) as a parameter to the function

The first two require the calling function to `free()` the returned value. The third allows the caller to decide how to allocate the string (stack or heap), but requires some sort of contract about the minumum size needed for the output string.

Comment: unless you wrap the method in a class, put the 'return' string as a global class attribute, and free resources on class destructor

Comment: @TheofanisPantelides You're talking C++. There is no such thing as a class attribute or a destructor here.

Comment: @DanielFischer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_science)#In_C_with_GCC_extensions

Comment: @TheofanisPantelides Didn't know that, interesting. But fortunately, the question is tagged C, not gcc :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when the function returns, then `Return` will be gone as well, so this behavior is undefined. It might work, but you should *never* rely on it.

Typically in C, you'd want to pass the "return" string as an argument instead, so that you don't have to `free` it all the time. Both require a local variable on the caller's side, but `malloc`'ing it will require an additional call to free the allocated memory and is also more expensive than simply passing a pointer to a local variable.

As for appending to the string, just use array notation (keep track of the current char/index) and don't forget to add a null character at the end.

Example:

```
int arg(char* ptr, char* S, int Num) {
    int i, Spaces = 0, cur = 0;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(S); i++) {
        if (S[i] == ' ') {
            Spaces++;
        }
        else if (Spaces == Num) {
            ptr[cur++] = S[i]; // append char
        }
        else if (Spaces > Num) {
            ptr[cur] = '\0';   // insert null char
            return 0;          // returns 0 on success
        }
    }

    ptr[cur] = '\0';           // insert null char
    return (cur > 0 ? 0 : -1); // returns 0 on success, -1 on error
}
```

Then invoke it like so:

```
char myArg[50];
if (arg(myArg, "this is an example", 3) == 0) {
    printf("arg is %s\n", myArg);
} else {
    // arg not found
}
```

Just make sure you don't overflow `ptr` (e.g.: by passing its size and adding a check in the function).

There are numbers of ways you could improve your code, but let's just start by making it meet the standard. ;-)

*P.S.: Don't `malloc` unless you **need to**. And in that case you don't.*

Comment: `Return` will be gone, but it is, right now, just a pointer to a string that exists outside the scope of the function. So in this particular case the scoping is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * Return;   //by the way horrible name for a variable.
Return = malloc(<some size>);
......
......
*(Return + index) = *(S+i);
```

Comment: By incrementing `Return` you can't return it anymore.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out...i was also doing *S++ which may cause calling code suffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign anything to a string literal such as "".

You may want to use your loop to determine the offsets of the start of the word in your string that you're looking for.  Then find its length by continuing through the string until you encounter the end or another space. Then, you can malloc an array of chars with size equal to the size of the offset+1 (For the null terminator.)  Finally, copy the substring into this new buffer and return it.

Also, as mentioned above, you may want to remove the strlen call from the loop - most compilers will optimize it out but it is indeed a linear operation for every character in the array, making the loop O(n**2).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *arg(const char *S, unsigned int Num) {
    char *Return = "";
    const char *top, *p;
    unsigned int Spaces = 0;
    int i = 0;

    Return=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    *Return = '\0';
    if(S == NULL || *S=='\0') return Return;
    p=top=S;
    while(Spaces != Num){
        if(NULL!=(p=strchr(top, ' '))){
            ++Spaces;
            top=++p;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(Spaces < Num) return Return;
    if(NULL!=(p=strchr(top, ' '))){
        int len = p - top;
        Return=(char*)realloc(Return, sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        strncpy(Return, top, len);
        Return[len]='\0';
    } else {
        free(Return);
        Return=strdup(top);
    }
    //printf("%s-\n", Return);
    return Return;
}

int main(){
    char *word;

    word=arg("make a quick function", 2);//quick
    printf("\"%s\"\n", word);

    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```